# Usando json para copiar os dados (Django)

Tags: json, django

Pensei melhor, e acho que vou usar json.

```
def entry_detail_json(request, pk):
    data = Entry.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    s = serializers.serialize("json", data)
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Mas estando na página

```
http://localhost:8000/entry/2/
```

como eu faço para me referir a página

```
http://localhost:8000/entry/json/2/
```

E atribui os valores na função a seguir para copiar os dados?

Eu consegui o resultado da seguinte forma:

```
<input name="new_proposal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ entry.id }}"
```

**views.py**

```
def create_proposal(request, employee_pk=1, **kwargs):
    f = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        f = request.GET['new_proposal']
    if f:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=employee_pk)  # TODO
        nlp = NumLastProposal.objects.get(pk=1)  # sempre pk=1
        # entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk', None))
        entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=f)
        obj = Proposal(
            num_prop=nlp.num_last_prop + 1,
            type_prop='R',
            category=entry.category,
            description=entry.description,
            work=entry.work,
            person=entry.person,
            employee=employee,
            seller=entry.seller,
        )
        obj.save()
        # Define que foi dado entrada
        entry.is_entry = True
        entry.save()
        # Incrementa o número do último orçamento
        nlp.num_last_prop += 1
        nlp.save()
        print('Orçamento criado com sucesso')
    return redirect('proposal_list')
```

Está funcionando, mas eu sei que não é a melhor forma de se tratar isso.

E no final eu acabei não usando o JSON. Como eu faria para usar o JSON ao invés de fazer como eu fiz?

```
[{"pk": 2, "fields": {"work": 2, "description": "Ih1vwUcIYwc0ce", "created": "2015-07-31T19:41:04.408Z", "priority": "u", "category": 1, "person": 45, "seller": 2, "is_entry": true, "modified": "2015-07-31T21:11:59.165Z"}, "model": "core.entry"}]
```

Comment: Não está claro suficiente o que você está querendo.

Comment: @Orion Repare que as informações que estou passando em obj = Proposal(...), os valores vêm de cada campo de entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=entry_detail_json(2)) # ou algo semelhante
O que eu queria fazer, e que talvez seja mais simples, é pegar todos os valores a partir do json que eu gerei no endereço da url, mas não sei como fazer isso. Estava tentando isso porque na verdade eu não conseguia pegar o id atual de Entry dentro da página.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender, tente reduzir o código apenas para o que interessa e edite a pergunta de forma mais clara, porque pessoalmente não estou conseguindo entender a dúvida.

Comment: @Orion editei a pergunta, espero que tenha esclarecido melhor.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva reabri a pergunta. Podes remover esse ultimo edit e colocar como resposta? Assim fica mais útil para quem tiver o mesmo problema no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo percebi, precisa de enviar o valor entry.id (neste caso 2) para a view "entry-detail-json" que, no seu caso, você está enviando por parametro GET, correcto?

**Pode dar um nome ao url e enviar o "entry.id" como parametro do url.**

Por exemplo, imagina que tem o url que irá processar o json:

```
 url(r'^entry-detail-json/(?P<pk>\d*)', 
     'link.para.entry_detail_json',  
      name='entry-detail-json')
```

Note o

```
... "name='entry-detail-json'"...
```

De modo a aceder este url no template onde tenha entry.id, basta escrever:

```
<a href="{% url 'entry-detail-json' pk=entry.id %}">Json entry</a>
```

Acho que no seu caso, você precisa mesmo dessa linha:

```
{% url 'nome_do_url' nome_do_parametro=valor_do_parametro %}
```

Neste caso o valor de "entry.id" irá ser injectado para a view como o nome "pk":

```
def entry_detail_json(request, pk):
    data = Entry.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    s = serializers.serialize("json", data)
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Também pode chamar o url de uma outra view:

```
return redirect('entry-detail-json', pk=entry.id)
```

Você pode até passar mais do que um parametro, tornando esse url numa espécie de json output

url:

```
url(r'^json-output/(?P<obj_type>\w*)/(?P<pk>\d*)',
    'link.para.json_output', 
     name='json-ouput')
```

view:

```
import json

def json_output(request, obj_type=None, pk=None):

    if obj_type is None or pk is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest

    if obj_type == "entry" :
        data = Entry.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data)), mimetype='application/json')
    elif obj_type == "other_object"
        data = OtherObject.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data)), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url 'json-output' obj_type="entry" pk=entry.id %}">Json entry</a>
<a href="{% url 'json-output' obj_type="other_object" pk=other.id %}">Json Object</a>
```

Espero que seja isso que procura.

Cumprimentos